Merge partially overlapping line geometries into a single line feature with QGIS, pyqgis, geopandas, shapely
I have a geopackage file with multiline features. The features are extractions from the same line geometries.
Some of those extracted lines do overlap, so they partially share the same geometry. Some are even sublines of other lines.
How can I merge those geometries into a single line-feature without duplicated parts?
It seems like a relative straighforward task, but I couldn't find any solution.
I tried the v.clean-Tool with break, but this doesn't seem to work, it doesn't find the overlaps, so this does not solve it.
I also tried shapely linemerge, but this also didn't have any effect, meaning the lines were still overlapping:
merged = gpd.GeoDataFrame(geometry = list(shapely.ops.linemerge(extractedLines).geoms))

What can I do instead?


To remove overlaps using shapely, shapely.union_all should do the trick.
If you don't only want to remove the overlaps, but also want the result to consist of as few linestrings as possible, you need to add a shapely.line_merge() call around shapely.union_all().
Code sample:
merged = gpd.GeoDataFrame(geometry=shapely.get_parts(shapely.union_all(extractedLines)))


Thank you very much! It worked! With unionMerged = gpd.GeoDataFrame(geometry=shapely.get_parts(shapely.line_merge(shapely.union_all(extractedLines)))) I managed to remove almost all overlapping parts! Very, very few overlaps still existed, which I then removed manually in about 5 minutes. Wow, great!

When removing overlapping lines with QGIS, I also managed to delete them by first applying Union, which checks for overlaps between features within the Input layer and creates separate features for overlapping and non-overlapping parts. The area of overlap will create as many identical overlapping features as there are features that participate in that overlap.
After that, delete duplicated geometries by applying Delete duplicate geometries.
